# I can't Split the text extracted from powerpoint into multiple lines

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I extracted some text within a shape the text, i printed it line by line into an output txt file for viewing before i actually do what i need to do.

the problem i'm having is that the text i'm extracting when opened with notepad++ i can see there is a the text split into multiple lines while in regular notepad it's one big chunk of text. Is there a way for me to detect that nextline for me to split the string?

Here's my code

```
int linecounter = 1;
bool isDetailPage = false;
Application pptApplication = new Application();
Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open(file, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
foreach (Slide _slide in pptPresentation.Slides) {
  tempOutput.Add("- Parsing Slide " + linecounter);
  foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape _shape in _slide.Shapes) {
    if(_shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue) {
      var textFrame = _shape.TextFrame;
      if(textFrame.HasText == MsoTriState.msoTrue) {
        var textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
        Match match = knowldgeSlide.Match(textRange.Text.ToString());
        if (match.Success) {
          isDetailPage = true;
        }
        if(isDetailPage) { //ignore other slides
          string[] lines = textRange.Text.ToString().Split(
            new[] { "\n" },
            StringSplitOptions.None
          );
          int t = 0;
          foreach(string x in lines) {
            tempOutput.Add("line " + t + ": " + x);
            t++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  isDetailPage = false;
  linecounter++;
}
```

Here's the extracted text from the powerpoint, which i want to split into 5 lines of strings.

```
line 0: Identify the four benefits you gain from convergence and OTN? (Source: Identify the need for the NCS 4000 Series in the OTN Environment) 
Virtualized network operations
The scalability 
Reduction in transport costs
Flexibility allows operators to employ the technologies
Service contracts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `"\r"` is used as a new line in addition to `"\n"`.  If the text is showing up in notepad++ with line breaks, then there is definitely something there that notepad++ is picking up on.  You can see the character values for each character by clicking View > Show Symbols > Show all characters.  When you look at it like this in notepad++, find whatever is at the end of each line and split based on that char in your C# code.

Comment: Thank you, this explains everything and I learned a nice new feature.

Answer (score 1):

Split on both `\r` and `\n`.

I like to do it this way:

```
string[] lines = textRange.Text.ToString().Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```